# Add to cart Button Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am facing problem in Add to cart button in my Website.(I am using Codeigniter Shopping Cart)

For now I am having button which is in the form. When I click add to Cart button, my product is added into the cart.

But I want something like - when I click add to cart button for first time its value should change to Remove product calling some method having Add function.

Similarly when I click on Same button with value Remove Product it should call other method having remove code and its value should change to Add to Cart.

I am having code in Javascript and AJAX,but I don't know how to call two different method using same button.

Below is the Code I tried.

```
<script>
instance.addCart.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = $(this);
            if (self.hasClass('btn-primary')){
                self.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default').text('Remove');
            } else {
                self.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary').text('Add to Cart');
            }
        });
</script>

 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-cart">Add to Cart</a>
```

I Know how to send data and call particular method in AJAX.

This is pretty Confusing. Please Help

Comment: I don't see neither code for ajax request, nor code for _two different methods_. Right now [code works](http://jsfiddle.net/xtfjonmn/) "as is"

Comment: This is what all I got. I don't know how to call 2 methods using AJAX on same button click.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the different functions in the `if/else` statement blocks?

```
if (self.hasClass('btn-primary'))
{
    self.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default').text('Remove');
    addToCart();
}
else
{
    self.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary').text('Add to Cart');
    removeFromCart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

**JS code:**

```
$('.btn_add_remove_cart').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.hasClass('add-cart')){ 
        // if it's add cart button, replace add-cart class by remove-cart and change label
        self.removeClass('add-cart').addClass('remove-cart').text('Remove');
    } else {
        // it's remove cart button, do the inverse
        self.removeClass('remove-cart').addClass('add-cart').text('Add to Cart');
    }
});
```

**HTML code:**

I added a new class `btn_add_remove_cart` just for jquery calls :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-cart btn_add_remove_cart">Add to Cart</a>
```